# Search if the file exist in the specific location using batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, search

Not sure if anyone can help me.
How can I search if a specific file in exist in the specific location/directory?

check the "mydatetime_computername.zip" is exits at disk d:\asd
if yes, delete the file at c:\mydatetime_computername.zip
else zip and copy again.

```
@echo off

net use L: /delete /y
goto 1 

:1
net use L: \\129.101.115.1\d$\triagelog grl@lock /user:testadmin /persistent:yes

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)

7za a -tzip "c:\%computername%-%mydate%.zip" "c:\temp" 

move C:\%computername%-%mydate%.zip *.* L:\Triagelog

for /r L:\Triagelog %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%computername%-%mydate%.zip"                     set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo %p%
::rmdir /f/q "C:\temp" 
del /f/q "C:\temp" 
echo File deleted.
) else (
echo Fail to search file..
)
```

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `if /?` to get output the help for this command. You can read about `if exist "path to file/folder" ...` Next I suggest to run in command prompt window `del /?` because in output help you can read that this command can also search in a directory tree for deleting a file on using `/S` option (search in subdirectories). So all you most likely need is `del /F /Q /S "d:\asd\mydatetime_computername.zip" 2>nul`.

Answer (score 0):

to check the existence of a file, use `if exist [path\]<filename>`

```
if exist "d:\asd\mydatetime_computername.zip" (
  del "c:\mydatetime_computername.zip"
) else (
 echo does not exist...
)
```

Comment: Actually my dedicatory/path are variable instead of name.

Comment: and what's the problem about that?

Comment: now I cant move my file to another directory. Is it the variables matter?

Comment: were do you set `%p%`? According to your code, it's never set, so it's always not defined. Also one line seems not to be complete: `for ... do if ...=... <command?>`